# Why no ConcurrentModificationException when one thread iterating (using Iterator) and other thread modifying same copy of non-thread-safe ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading, iterator, concurrentmodification

**Some background:**
When a collection is iterated using `Iterator` then there could `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` because under the hoods when the `Iterator` object is created then the modification count (`modCount`) of the collection or ArrayList is captured and on each iteration using `Iterator.next()` it is checked if `modCount` has changed, if so then throw `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

*On creating iterator object (from `ArrayList`'s `Iterator` implementation):*
`int expectedModCount = modCount;`

Below method gets called upon `Iterator.next()`, which throws exception (from `ArrayList`'s `Iterator` implementation):

```
final void checkForComodification() {
    if (modCount != expectedModCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

I could very well reproduce it using below code:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
                stringList.add("a");
                stringList.add("b");
                stringList.add("c");
                Iterator<String> iterator = stringList.iterator();
                System.out.println("Got iterator object");
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String player = iterator.next();
                    player.toString();
                    System.out.println("UpperCase: " + player.toUpperCase());
                    iterator.remove();
                    stringList.add("a1"); //This is root cause of exception.
                }
```

**Question:**

- If I try to modify the list using a different thread (code is below) then I do not get `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` but if I do using same thread then I get the exception.

If I understand correct then still on each pass of `Iterator.next()` from first thread, `Iterator.checkForComodification()` will be called internally, and since my second thread has modified the list, so latest `modCount` will not be equal `Iterator.expectedModCount` which was initialized when `Iterator` object was created, hence exception should have occurred from `Iterator.checkForComodification()`. Right?

I have verified that list is getting updated from thread 2 and iterator from thread 1 is able to print the new value, because I can see the "d" value printed which is being added by second thread.

```
private static void iteratorException() {
    final List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("T1");
            stringList.add("a");
            stringList.add("b");
            stringList.add("c");
            Iterator<String> iterator = stringList.iterator();
            System.out.println("Got iterator object");
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String player = iterator.next();
                player.toString();
                System.out.println("UpperCase: " + player.toUpperCase());
                iterator.remove();
                //stringList.add("a1");
            }
        }
    };

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("T2");
            stringList.add("d");
            stringList.remove("a");
            System.out.println("finished T2");
        }
    };

    thread.start();
    thread2.start();
}
```

Comment: How do you guarantee that the `add` and `remove` in one thread get called after you acquire the `Iterator` in the other thread and start iterating? Hint: race condition.

Comment: `Thread.start()`  takes a long and unpredictable time (relatively speaking in computing terms.)  You have no code there that does anything to guarantee the iteration starts before you'd altered the list.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you. I got it, I somehow missed it. My bad. I slept my second thread for 1 second and first thread as well for 1 second from the while loop, so that there is no unwanted race condition and I got the exception. I will delete the question.

Comment: @Affe I actually had sleep in first thread in while loop but I didn't post it. I missed to have it in second thread.  Sotirios opened my eyes, and I got that. Thanks for your note though. I will delete the question.

Comment: Note that, even with the correct interlacing, since modCound is not volatile, you have no visibility guarantee, and the first thread might not see the modification made by the second thread. This behavior tries to help you detect bugs, but provides no guarantee.

Comment: @JBNizet So, it means if some variable is not volatile and shared among threads, then all threads may or may not see the latest modification? But in my case, there is an ArrayList object and it will be on heap, and hence all threads will have visibility to its state, right? My understanding is that it is for primitive whose value is on stack, and hence thread-dependent.

Comment: All threads will have visibility to its state is you synchronize them properly.

Comment: @JBNizet Do visibility go hand in hand with synchronization? If there is a primitive shared among multiple threads, then even if threads are properly synchronized, its state change will not be reflected if that primitive is not marked as `volatile`. Right?

Comment: This is too complex to be answered in a comment. Read the last paragraph of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html, and, if you're interested enough, read *Java Concurrency in Practice*, by Brian Goetz.