# While modifying ArrayList with one thread and iterating it with another thread, it is throwing ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: multithreading, iterator, concurrentmodification

I was trying below code.

```
public class IteratorFailFastTest {

    private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public IteratorFailFastTest() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }

    public void runUpdateThread() {
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
                    list.add(i);

                }
            }
        });

        thread2.start();
    }


    public void runIteratorThread() {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.listIterator();

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Integer number = iterator.next();
                System.out.println(number);
                }

            }
        });

        thread1.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        IteratorFailFastTest tester = new IteratorFailFastTest();

        tester.runIteratorThread();
        tester.runUpdateThread();
    }

}
```

It is throwing ConcurrentModificationException sometimes and at times running successfully.

What I don't understand is, since there are 2 different methods each containing one thread. They will execute one by one. When one thread finishes modifying the list, Thread 2 will start iterating.

I also referred to this link([Why no ConcurrentModificationException when one thread iterating (using Iterator) and other thread modifying same copy of non-thread-safe ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372131/why-no-concurrentmodificationexception-when-one-thread-iterating-using-iterator)), but it is different scenario.

So, Why is it throwing this exception? Is it because of threads?

Can somebody explain?

Comment: Please do not link to code/article. Edit your question to include actual code fragment.

Comment: @Bohemian: I have edited the post.

Comment: There should be no CME: the iterator is created but not used

Comment: @Bohemian:  Its my bad. Have added the iterator code.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting two threads and then doing no further synchronization.

Sometimes, both threads will be running at the same time, and you will get the CME.  Other times, the first thread will finish before the second thread actually starts executing.  In that scenario won't get a CME.

The reason you get the variation could well be down to things like load on your system.  Or it could simply be down to the fact that the thread scheduler is non-deterministic.

Your threads actually do a tiny amount of work, compared to the overheads of creating / starting a thread.  So it is not surprising that one of them can return from its `run()` method very quickly.

Comment: That would be the case if I were calling them like 'Thread obj = new Thread(); obj.start(); Thread obj2 = new Thread(); obj2.start();' But these are 2 different methods. They will be called one by one. Aren't they?

Comment: Yes.  They are.  But read the javadocs for `start()` carefully.  They make no guarantees that the child thread will be *running* by the time that the `start()` call returns to the caller,  In fact, it is irrelevant that the two `start()` calls are in different methods.